# Plotting: every point in different color

Tags: plotting

I would like to plot/scatter a few points, but each of them should be in different color. I need this, because color should store extra information, let's say OX means age, OY means hight and color of point indicates a person. Is it possible to do? Thanks for any help

Edit:
Solved. Thank you for your answers. I decided to create ListPlot and treat every point as seperate plot, because it's important for me to remember which point represents which "person".

Comment: often simplest to just use graphics directives for this, see `Graphics`,`Point`

Comment: So do you want each one in different color or do you want the color to reflect already existing values? \

Answer (score 3):

All the same colour

```
ListPlot[MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #1} &, Prime[Range[25]]]]
```

All different colours

```
ListPlot[MapIndexed[List@{#2[[1]], #1} &, Prime[Range[25]]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have some list of points:

```
data = Table[{i, Random[]}, {i, 0, 10}];
```

Then

```
ListPlot[Flatten[{data}, {2}], PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large]]
```

gives you what you want:

[image]

You can use `PlotStyle` to define the color to be used.